# Azure container service DC/OS install net core images

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, containers, dcos

My problem is that I have a set of net core applications that I created and I send them to Docker Hub:

```
$ docker push username/appname
```

On the other side I create on Azure Container Service with DC/OS, and login the server with terminal

```
$ ssh -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa -L 80:localhost:80 -f -N username@servernamemgmt.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200 -v
```

but I cant understand how to install my docker images.

Answer (score 0):

In DC/OS, in order to deploy and run your Docker containers, you use [Marathon](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/marathon/) (for long-running services such as an app server, etc.) or [Jobs](https://dcos.io/docs/1.8/usage/jobs/) for one-off or scheduled tasks (think: distributed cron). You don't ssh into nodes and manually pull/run them.

Comment: this doesnt answer his question

Comment: OK so in marathon I call username/appname? and open the requested port?

Comment: @michealhausenblas  how do I install from marathon?

Comment: well, if it did, you would link to the page which describes how to configure docker registry with marathon, else its the same as linking to google

Comment: Apologies if I misread the question but I didn't interpret it around how to use or configure a Docker registry but how to run a Docker container. Maybe it would help if @shaharnakash tells us what exactly the goal is?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Well, I think Michael is right with linking to the Marathon usage docs. Configuring Marathon to use a private Docker registry is probably needed as well, but that's not specifically asked in the question. See https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html#using-a-private-docker-repository for a reference

Comment: what do you mean not asked? `I cant understand how to install my docker images.`?

Comment: Define 'install'. That's a made up term. There is run and there is pull.

Answer (score 0):

If your docker images are already on Docker hub, in order to use them on your DC/OS cluster you typically use Marathon.
Since you say you configured an SSH tunnel with port forwarding (this is an important step), you should be able to access the Marathon UI using http://localhost/Marathon . Then, click on 'Create Application' where you can specify it's settings. The part you are probably looking for is in the second menu item - 'Docker Container' (menu to the left inside the Create Container dialog). There you can specify an image. This by default goes to Docker Hub, so you can write 'username/appname' in the 'Image' text box.
There are additional settings but I think this is what your question was about.

More information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-mesos-marathon-ui